# What is $\mathbb R^{n \times m}$ in $f:\mathbb R^{n \times m} \to \mathbb R^n$?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, notation, control-theory

I think of $\mathbb R^{n\times m}$ as a matrix of size $n \times m$. But what is $f:\mathbb R^{n \times m} \to \mathbb R^n$ and $g:\mathbb R^{n \times m} \to \mathbb R^q$ in following?

> Consider
> \begin{align}
> \dot x (t) &= f(x(t),u(t)) \tag 1 \\
> 0 &\geq g(x(t),u(x)) \tag 2
> \end{align}
> where $x(t) \in \mathbb R^n$ and $u(t) \in \mathbb R^m$. Both $f:\mathbb R^{n \times m} \to \mathbb R^n$ and $g:\mathbb R^{n \times m} \to \mathbb R^q$ are continuously differentiable.

Comment: Should probably be $\Bbb{R}^n\times \Bbb{R}^m$, but for $g$, it doesn't make sense to have $\Bbb{R}^q$ as the target space unless $q=1$, because there is no natural order relation, so it doesn't makes sense to say $0 \geq g(\dots)$

Comment: The notation $\mapsto$ is not usually used as an arrow from the domain to the codomain of a function.  The notation $x\mapsto y$ usually means the element $x$ is mapped to $y$ (under some function).  Please use $f:A\to B$ instead of $f:A\mapsto B$ if $A$ and $B$ are the domain and the codomain of a function $f$.  When you write $f:A\mapsto B$, it may confuse some user that $f$ is a function that maps an element $A$ in some domain to an element $B$ in some codomain.

Comment: Hi @peek-a-boo! Thanks! Can we also write $\Bbb{R}^{n+m}$, i.e. is it true that we have $\Bbb{R}^n\times \Bbb{R}^m=\Bbb{R}^{n+m}$?

Comment: Hi @Batominovski! I used the notation from the article, but thanks for the clarification. :)

Comment: @JDoeDoe well, it depends how strict you want to be set theoretically (in which case you might be more inclined to say $\Bbb{R}^n \times \Bbb{R}^m \cong \Bbb{R}^{n+m}$ to indicate there is a natural bijection between the two spaces), but for most purposes yea sure, I think that's fine to identify the two spaces, and use an equality (and I think most people would agree this is fine).

Comment: @peek-a-boo! I see, great! You also wrote that $q$ only make sense if $q=1$. But, for instance, if $m=n=2$ and $q=2$ we have $g: \mathbb R^4 \rightarrow \mathbb R^2$, doesn't this mean two inequalities? I.e. $0\geq g(x(t),u(x))=(g_1(x(t),u(t)),g_2(x(t),u(t))) \iff  0\geq g_1(x(t),u(t))\text{ and }  0\geq g_2(x(t),u(t))$?

Comment: if that's what you really want to say, you should make it explicitly known, because it's not common to use $\geq$ or $\leq$ in $\Bbb{R}^q$ for $q>1$ (probably because it is not possible to preserve the vector space structure and also give it the strucutre of an ordered field). Anyway the real message is that anything which is not "standard" should be explicitly mentioned (and sometimes even "standard" things should be mentioned explicitly just to avoid confusion)